# postgreSQL query empty array fields within jsonb column

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

```
device_id | device
-----------------------------
9809      | { "name" : "printer", "tags" : [] }    
9810      | { "name" : "phone", "tags" : [{"count": 2, "price" : 77}, {"count": 3, "price" : 37} ] }
```

For the following postgres SQL query on a jsonb column "device" that contains array 'tags':

```
SELECT t.device_id, elem->>'count', elem->>'price'
FROM   tbl t, json_array_elements(t.device->'tags') elem
where t.device_id = 9809
```

device_id is the primary key.

I have two issues that I don't know how to solve:

1. tags is an array field that may be empty, in which case I got 0 rows. I want output no matter tags is empty or not. Dummy values are ok.
2. If tags contain multiple elements, I got multiple rows for the same device id. How to aggregate those multiple elements into one row?

Comment: please show json example?..

Comment: please provide some json sample

Answer (score 6):

Your first problem can be solved by using a left outer join, that will substitute NULL values for missing matches on the right side.

The second problem can be solved with an aggregate function like `json_agg`, `array_agg` or `string_agg`, depending on the desired result type:

```
SELECT t.device_id,
       jsonb_agg(elem->>'count'),
       jsonb_agg(elem->>'price')
FROM tbl t
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.device->'tags') elem
      ON TRUE
GROUP BY t.device_id;
```

You will get a JSON array containing just `null` for those rows where the array is empty, I hope that is ok for you.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz. I tried and looks like the join takes very long time.

Comment: Sure, this query means a sequential scan. If the table is big, it will take long. No way around that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe WELL DONE. This saved me about a days-worth of troubleshooting!

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe is it possible to follow this approach and get an empty json array instead of an array with null?

Comment: I assume this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68807026/6464308) that I don't understand. Is your problem that `count` and `proce` are JSON `null`, and you want to omit those from the result? If yes, please edit your other question and clarify that.