# left lateral join on true clause Postgresql not getting it

Tags: postgresql, lateral-join

Trying hard to understand *left join lateral*.

```
begin;
create temp table manufacturers(id serial primary key, name text);
create temp table get_product_names (pid integer, id integer, product text, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY(id)   REFERENCES manufacturers(id) );
insert into manufacturers(name) values('m1'),('m2'),('m3'),('m4'),('m5');
insert into get_product_names(pid,id, product) values(1,1,'typea');
insert into get_product_names(pid,id, product) values(2,2,'typeb');
insert into get_product_names(pid,id, product) values(3,4,'typec');
commit;
```

Quote from manual

> It is often particularly handy to LEFT JOIN to a LATERAL subquery, so
> that source rows will appear in the result even if the LATERAL
> subquery produces no rows for them. For example, if
> get_product_names() returns the names of products made by a
> manufacturer, but some manufacturers in our table currently produce no
> products, we could find out which ones those are like this:

```
SELECT m.name
FROM manufacturers m LEFT JOIN LATERAL get_product_names(m.id) pname ON true
WHERE pname IS NULL;
```

But when I execute the code: following error occurred.

```
No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So How can I replicate the *left lateral join on true* clause. Or where did my code went wrong?

Comment: So how does your function `get_product_names()` look like?

Comment: Overall I think I don't understand left lateral join on true. I dont understand the answer in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722669/postgresql-query-empty-array-fields-within-jsonb-column 
@a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

You didn't make a function named get_product_names(int).

You can't lateral join to a bare table name.  It must be to a subquery, are to a function.

Comment: would you please give an example. The manual  seems very vague to me.